# Issue while using expect script in bash script

Tags: expect

I learned from the same site that we can embed expect script in bash script as shown below:

```
echo $hostname
/usr/bin/expect -<<EOD
spawn ssh "-o StrictHostKeyChecking no " bmaddi@10.102.238.158
sleep 5
expect "$*"
    send -- "scp \"-o StrictHostKeyChecking no\"  file user@hostname: \r"
    expect "$*"
    send -- "exit \r"
expect eof
EOD
```

When I am trying to execute the above script which logs on to another host and does some stuff over there and then come back to original host, I am facing the following error:

invalid command name "EOD"
    while executing
"EOD "
. It is not recognizing EOD as end of the usage of expect script and hence abruptly ending there.  Can some one please suggest a solution for this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably need either `-f - <<EOD` or remove the hyphen before `<<`. Also, do you intend your expect statement to use the shell's `$*`? If not, use `<<'EOD'` to effectively single quote the entire expect script.

Comment: Hi Glenn, thanks for the suggestion, but that did not help. The issue still persists.

Comment: Is there any whitespace before or after the closing `EOD`?

Comment: Perfect.. white space before the EOD is the culprit. Never imagined a space would eat out 2 days of my life. Kudos to you Glenn. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: bash documentation for here-documents [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents)